# Packing an Outlook Add ins created with Yeoman

Tags: outlook-addin, office-store

I've created an Outlook add ins using **Yeoman** not Visual Studio and now I want to submit it to the office store.

The add-ins is targeting *Outlook Desktop* and *Outlook 365*.

In the documentation there's an example about packing the add ins using *Visual Studio 2015*. Here's the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio

Is there any tutorial about packing the add ins when it is created with **Yeoman?**

Also, once I've packed it to which host it should be submitted? To Azure.com? May I host the Add ins in my own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a "package", only a single XML Manifest file. The Store only hosts/provides the manifest. Where you host the actual application/add-in is up to you (assuming it is secured/HTTPS).

When you submit your add-in to the store, the only assets you supply are the manifest and screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Now I've a doubt, in the docs Microsoft says that when you submit the add ins (the manifest as you told me) you can't do any change to the add ins until it's published. How they know I did a change after the first publication if I'm hosting the add ins?

Comment: You cannot change the manifest until it has completed validation. In other words, you cannot submit a v2 before v1 has validated. Changes to the add-in code itself are not tracked and bug fixes are certainly fine to push out as needed. On the whole, locking down your web app is on an honor system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help